# How can I navigate to a windows generated control?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawstring

I have this code

```
private void picturebox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Percent == 100)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Completed!", font, Brushes.Black, new Point(3, 2));
        }
    }
```

And I want to navigate if from here:

```
public void Complete()
{
    picRooms_Paint();//How can I reach picRooms_Paint from here and draw the string?
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you set the `Text` instead? unless you want some kind of custom drawn string. By the way, what is your `picRooms`? a pictureBox?

Comment: What you probably want to do is invalidate picRooms so that the Paint event is initiated.  I think it is something like picRooms.Invalidate();

Comment: How are these methods implemented?  Are they in the same class?  Also, your method call `picRooms_Paint()` **will not work** in the example above.  Initially you were passing it two overloads `object sender, PaintEventArgs e`, and aren't following that same pattern in the second method.

Comment: I have a certain font that isn't pre-installed on C#. And yes, it is a picturebox.

Comment: They are both in Form1. My code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/Nnwjih3z)

Comment: @EricJ.'s `Invalidate()` should work, as well as `picRooms.Refresh()`.  Just make sure the main UI thread isn't stuck in any tight loops that would prevent it from updating itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your example what `picRooms` is, so I can't tell you how to access its Graphics from elsewhere.

Though as a general API improvement, it would be better to move the functional code out of the event handler into a method where it *can* be re-used;

```
private void DrawComplete(Graphics g)
{
    if (Percent == 100)
    {
        g.DrawString("Completed!", font, Brushes.Black, new Point(3, 2));
    }
}
```

And now you can call that method from anywhere;

```
private void picRooms_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    DrawComplete(e.Graphics)
}

public void Complete()
{
    DrawComplete(this.CreateGraphics());
}
```

Also worth nothing that in your example, since `Complete` does nothing else, you might as well follow this example, but put the functional code in `Complete`, not add another method the way I have.

Comment: Amazing idea, then I can just load the graphics into the picturebox!
Thanks so much!

Comment: I think you'll find this is more complicated when you get into it; the PictureBox may just redraw itself when the form is painted, depending on what other code you've got going on.

Comment: Yea I'm having trouble loading the graphics into the picturebox.
I want it to keep trying until the percent is at 100 if possible.